# Proving a sequence of functions does not converge uniformly. Can it be assumed that $N\geq 1$ an epsilon N proof?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the function $f_n(x) = \frac{n}{nx+1}$ for $x \in(0,1)$
, where $n$ is in the natural numbers, does not converge uniformly to $\frac{1}{x}$ by proving $\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall N, \exists x, \exists n> N$ such that $|f_n(x) - \frac{1}{x}| \geq \epsilon$. I know it says for all $N$, but it doesn't make much sense to me that we'd be given an $N$ less than $1$ since the function requires that $n$ is in the natural numbers. I don't need help with the proof, just clarification on whether $N$ could be negative.

Comment: We have not covered simple convergence as of yet, only uniform and pointwise.

Comment: Simple = "pointwise."

Comment: I totally missed inserting that the domain was for $x\in (0,1)$. The question actually does ask us to prove pointwise convergence for all $x$ in the domain $(0,1)$ and I've done that. My ONLY question here is if it can be assumed the $N$ is non-negative.

Comment: Perhaps I should have shown my proof from the start. Let $\epsilon =\frac{1}{4}$ let $n = N+1$, let $x=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $|\frac{n}{nx+1} - \frac{1}{x}| = \frac{1}{x(nx+1)}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{N}(\frac{N+1}{N+1} + 1)} = \frac{1}{\frac{2}{N}} = \frac{N}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2} \geq \epsilon$

Comment: But it does convergence simply, for any given $x$ in the specified domain (which I stupidly forgot to mention earlier so you may have missed), $f_n(x)$ converges to $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Yes, you are right. $f_n(x)$ converges simply to $1/x.$

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is getting way too complicated, but if you really want...

**Theorem**

Let $p(\epsilon,x,n)$ be some proposition. Suppose it is proven that
$$\exists\epsilon,\,\forall N\geq1,\,\exists x,\,\exists n>N\,|\,p(\epsilon,x,n)\text{.}$$
Then it is also true that
$$\exists\epsilon,\,\forall N\in\mathbb{R},\,\exists x,\,\exists n>N\,|\,p(\epsilon,x,n)\text{.}$$

**Proof**

By hypothesis, some $\epsilon$ exists. Pick the same $\epsilon$. We are now given $N\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $N\geq1$, then obviously use the hypothesis to find $x$ and $n$.

Now suppose that $N<1$. By hypothesis we can find $x$, $n>1$ such that $p(\epsilon,x,n)$ is true. Then $n>1>N$ and therefore we have found $x$, $n>N$ such that $p(\epsilon,x,n)$ is true.

Comment: My only issue is that in my proof I picked $x=\frac{1}{N+1}$ where $x\in (0,1)$ and then on the last inequality right before I say everything is greather than or equal to epsilon, I have an $\frac{N}{2}$ (It looks like $\frac{N}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2} \geq \epsilon$) So if $N$ could be negative, my proof falls apart in multiple ways.

Comment: The argument above proves $\exists\epsilon\forall N\geq1\exists x\exists n>N|\text{statement}\,\Rightarrow\,\exists\epsilon\forall N\exists x\exists n>N|\text{statement}$ by copying. So prove the statement assuming $N\geq1$.

Comment: I'm don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: See rewrite. Just prove using $N\geq1$, as asked.